# String to display number of occurrences of unique values in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string that I am converting to an ArrayList with the intention of counting the number of particular values in the list.

My string may look like this :

```
String myString = "Living Room, Bedroom, Bedroom, Bedroom, Bathroom, Bathroom, Family Room."
```

I'm currently finding the number of occurences of unique values in this way:

```
Map<String, Long> count = Stream.of(myString.split(",")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
```

What's the best way to go about this so that I can print something along the lines of "My home includes 1 Living Room, 3 Bedrooms, 2 Bathrooms, and 1 Family Room."

---

For the moment, my solution is the following. I haven't yet accepted an answer, because I think the way I followed through is a little clunky:

```
String newDescription = "My Home includes ";

public String getDescription(){
    String myDescription = home.getDescription();

    Map<String, Long> count = Stream.of(myDescription.split(",")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));

    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : count.entrySet()){
        newDescription = newDescription + entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey() + "(s), ";
    }
    return newDescription;
}
```

---

I was previously going about it in this way, but another SO user suggested the change:

```
public ArrayList convertDescription(){
    //getDescription is inherited from another class to provide a string like the myString example above
    String myDescription = home.getDescription(); 

    ArrayList<String>Map<String, listDescriptionLong> =count new= ArrayList<String>(ArraysStream.asListof(myDescription.split(",")));

    int livingRoomOccurrences = Collections.frequencycollect(listDescription, "Living Room");
    int bedroomOccurrences = CollectionsCollectors.frequencygroupingBy(listDescription, "Bedroom");
    int bathroomOccurrencesw =-> Collections.frequency(listDescriptionw, "Bathroom");
    int familyRoomOccurrences = CollectionsCollectors.frequencycounting(listDescription, "Family Room");
    int kitchenOccurrences = Collections.frequency(listDescription, "Kitchen");
    int walkInClosetOccurrences = Collections.frequency(listDescription, "Walk-in Closet");
    //not sure what I should return to make it easy to override getDescription with the proper string formatting
    return listDescription;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return home.getDescription();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the frequency of all elements and extract what you need rather than scanning the collection again and again.

```
Map<String, Long> count = Stream.of(myString.split(","))
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting());
```

Comment: Okay, this looks more elegant. I'm trying to get more info on the w ->  w syntax...I'm new to java

Comment: @user25976 it's a function which returns whatever you are given.  This is needed as the first function/argument to `groupingBy` has to provide the key, but you want the key to be the word unaltered so the function doesn't do anything. e.g. say you did `w -> w.toLowerCase()` it would count the words in lower case so that the case would be ignored. This means that `"and"` and `"And"` and `"AND"` would all be counted as `"and"`

Comment: @user25976 you could do `w -> w.length()` This would make the key, the length of the word instead of the words itself. Or you could so `w -> w.charAt(0)` and the key would be the first letter of each word instead.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to use the map? I've been working on a solution, but haven't gotten any closer than just retrieving the keys and values individually. I think my difficulty is not necessarily knowing which strings will be present.

Comment: @user25976 You don't need to know which strings/keys are present.  You can just iterate over all the entries in a for-loop or use another stream to process the results.